# What happens to the electric field lines if 2 charges ($+q$, $+q$) are placed near each other?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, vectors

Imagine 2 charges placed close to each other. I know that each individual charge has field lines pointing outwards in all direction from the charge, so what happens to the field lines that "mingle" with the field lines from the other charge? There are 2 cases that I'm most curious about:

1. The straight line from one charge to another. What happens to the field lines here? Is the electric field zero in the straight path between the charges?
2. The crossing of the field lines above or below the straight path. What can be said about the electric field when the field lines cross?

Answer (score 0):

The electric field at a point is defined as the force on a unit positive charge at that point.
Electric field lines are just a visual aid with a property that at any point on the electric field line the direction of the electric field is along the direction of the tangent at that point.
So when you have two sets of fields overlapping as you do with your two charges at each point the electric fields due to the two charges have to be added vectorially and the tangent to an electric field line which passes through that point must be along the line of the electric field.
So it is impossible for field lines to cross as if they did that would mean that there would be two direction of the force on a charge at the point of intersection of the electric field lines, which is impossible.

**1** Some where along that electric field line there is a break in the line and that occurs at the point where the electric field is zero.
That point is sometimes called a "neutral point".

**2** Have a look at [Electric Field Lines for Configurations of Two or More Charges](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-4/Electric-Field-Lines) where it will be explained to you that a new set of electric field lines are generated when the electric field of two charges combine.